# Comparison of boiling points between 2‐butanol and isobutanol

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, boiling-point

Which has higher boiling points among butan‐2‐ol (**1**) and 2‐methylpropan‐1‐ol (**2**)?

[image: 1: 2‐butanol; 2: isobutanol]

I know that branching decreases the boiling points, but I want to know how position of substituents affects the melting (m.p.) and boiling points (b.p.). Google search only resulted in the b.p. of isobutyl alcohol listed in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isobutanol): 107.9 °C.

Comment: 2-butanol should be written instead of 1-methyl propanol as it is an incorrect IUPAC name.

Comment: 2-butanol boils at $99°$C - $100°$C

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/132765/why-is-the-boiling-point-of-homologous-primary-secondary-tertiary-alcohols-w

Comment: @Infinite The correct IUPAC name is butan-2-ol